# Harm/Infliction/Pain/Negativity in Hinduism?

Tags: belief, scripture, philosophy, karma

I was just reading about Hinduism online and I'm fascinated my it.
I do have a question though.
From what I understand, one of the principles of Hinduism is to not inflict suffering on another being.

My question is, if someone were to enjoy inflicting pain on life and wishes to achieve the destruction of the world, what would this be known as?

What does it mean? What should they do? What would other hindus do if they were to meet an individual such as this?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! you can see questions under "karma" to get answers for your questions. Briefly "KARMA" is  your actions done  physically and mentally. good begets good, bad begets bad. Well that type of sadistic behavior would leads to  destruction of that person, may or may not immediately. KARMA is huge and complex topic and  can't be narrated in one answer.

Answer (score 3):

A person with such characteristics is known to have tamasic traits. There are three *gunas* - *sattwa*, *rajas*, and *tamas*. These are described in Chapters 14, 17, and 18 of the *Gita*. There are other answers on HinduismSE which describe the *gunas*, do a search.

Briefly, in the *Gita*, Krishna says of a person with tamas: 'the fruit of ignorance is tamas', 'those who are steeped in tamas, being weighted down by the tendencies of the lowest guna, go downward', 'if it [the embodied soul] meets with death when tamas prevails, it is born in the wombs of creatures devoid of reason', 'the action that is undertaken through ignorance, without regard to consequences or loss of injury, and without regard to one's ability--that action is said to be of the nature of tamas.'